# SimpleOpenGlControl on Usercontrol

Tags: c#, visual-studio, opengl, tao

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error with tao SimpleOpenGlControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9230325/error-with-tao-simpleopenglcontrol)

I am creating an usercontrol contains a "Tao.Platform.Windows.SimpleOpenGlControl" .
In my control's constructor, I have

```
InitializeComponent();
ogl1.InitializeContexts();
```

.
My problem:
When I use the control on a "Windows Forms Application" it's ok, but if I hibernate the computer, when visual studio is open and form that contains the control, is in design mode, after hibernate this error comes up:

Fatal Error
can not activate the gl rendering context

What's wrong here?