# Error with tao SimpleOpenGlControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, opengl, tao-framework

I am creating an usercontrol contains a "Tao.Platform.Windows.SimpleOpenGlControl".
In my control's constructor, I have

```
{
    InitializeComponent();
    simpleOpenGlControl1.InitializeContexts();
}
```

My problem:
When I use the control on a "Windows Forms Application" it's ok, but if I put the computer at hibernate or sleep mode, when visual studio is open and form that contains the control, is in design mode, the next time I turn it on this error comes up:

```
Fatal Error
can not activate the gl rendering context
```

and visual studio is not responding!
What's wrong here? I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Old questions are not removed! Found your duplicate and flagged it. But 1+ for the afford to post the answer after a few month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem in this way:
In control's InitializeComponent(); I removed simpleOpenGlControl1 Initialization and then in control's Load() function, I have

```
isDesignMode = LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime;
if (!isDesignMode)
{
    // init simpleOpenGlControl1
}
```

Now when my control is used in a project, there is no simpleOpenGlControl1 in design mode to make problem!

Answer (score 1):

I am using Tao framework.
After implementing OpenGL chart solution, I encounter those error.
Every time I tried to close form, error occurred.
After few times of debugging, I found the reason.
The reason is like this.
On my form closing, Draw function tried to use `OpenGlControl` object ONE MORE TIME.
So I make condition to check the additional flag.